# Is anything bigger on the inside apart from Time Lord technology?

Tags: doctor-who, time-lord

Has there ever been anything in, or mentioned in, the Whoniverse that is bigger on the inside apart from Time Lord technology?

I am obviously aware of Tardises. There was also an object which turned out to be a Time Lord prison type thing with a multitude of Daleks inside

What I want to know is are there any examples of other species or civilizations who achieved similar technology?

I'm happy for answers from TV, books, comics, radio plays, spin offs and anything else considered as canon as Who gets.

Comment: There's the Teselecta, but that doesn't really count because you get shrunk to go inside rather than it being actually bigger on the inside.

Comment: The machine in The Carnival of Monsters (back in the Jon Pertwee days) also shrunk its contents (people, steamships, giant monsters) to achieve the same effect.

Comment: The Transmat Capsule in Mawdryn Undead is apparently bigger on the inside and not time-lord technology, but I've not found anything to indicate whether it's actually bigger inside or not.

Comment: I guess [Hermione Granger's handbag](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Hermione_Granger%27s_beaded_handbag) doesn't count.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Dalek time machine](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Dalek_time_machine) first seen in ["The Chase"](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/The_Chase_(TV_story)) was also dimensionally transcendent (bigger on the inside), as was the [Genesis Ark](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Genesis_Ark) seen in the New Series episode ["Doomsday"](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Doomsday_(TV_story)). I don't know if any species other than Time Lords and Daleks were ever shown to have this technology, though.

edit: As Rand al'Thor points out in a comment, some dialogue in "Doomsday" (transcript [here](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/28-13.htm)) indicates the Daleks stole the Genesis Ark from the Time Lords rather than building it themselves:

> MICKEY: But why would they build something they can't open themselves?
>
> BLACK DALEK: The technology is stolen. The Ark is not of Dalek design.
>
> ROSE: Then who built it?
>
> BLACK DALEK: The Time Lords. This is all that survives of their Home World.

On the other hand, some dialogue in "The Chase" (transcript [here](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/2-8.htm)) indicates the time machine there was at least built by the Daleks, though it's possible they learned some technological secrets from the Time Lords:

> BLACK: Give your report.
>
> DALEK: Our time machine has been completed.

And aside from the fact that we see it appears smaller outside than inside, there is also this bit of dialogue when the Doctor boards the Dalek time machine:

> DOCTOR: Oh, I'd be delighted! You know, this must be an extremely advanced machine. Wherever we went, it followed us with such great precision and accuracy. You could travel anywhere in it.
>
> VICKI: It's huge inside, you know, just like the Tardis.

Comment: Thanks, The Genesis Ark doesn't count because it was made by the Time Lords I believe. The Dalek time machine does though if the Daleks made it themselves rather than stealing it.

Comment: The Genesis Ark at least was said (frequently, by the Daleks) to be "Time Lord technology". I haven't seen "The Chase", but I think the whole concept of Time Lords hadn't really been invented then - that's easily retconned to be Time Lord technology too.